# How to pick specifics cells in a xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, import

I have some excel files who looklike this :

[image: input]

I had never read a file like that before in Python so I'm kind of lost.

So when I import one of them, it looklike this :

[image: output]

I cannot work with that.

Do you know some tips to import correctly those data ?

My goal is to sum all the file, like having a final file who had in E16 ->  E16 of file1 + E16 of file2 +...+E16 of file n.

And so on for each cells who contains an number.

But I cannot sum with this mess... Any ideas how to do that more efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help you:

```
# import openpyxl module
import openpyxl
 
# Call a Workbook() function of openpyxl
# to create a new blank Workbook object
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
 
# Get workbook active sheet 
# from the active attribute.
sheet = wb.active
 
# writing to the cell of an excel sheet
sheet['A1'] = 200
sheet['A2'] = 300
sheet['A3'] = 400
sheet['A4'] = 500
sheet['A5'] = 600
 
# The value in cell A7 is set to a formula
# that sums the values in A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 .
sheet['A7'] = '= SUM(A1:A5)'
 
# save the file
wb.save("sum.xlsx")
```

Comment: My values are in different files, that's also works ? Because here, it seems, you create manually your data, mine are already there, in different files.

Comment: yes for example sheet['A1'] = sheet['A1'] ].value here value will be your exiting data value

Comment: Yeah I see, I will try it and keep you in touch, thanks sir !

Comment: How to telll sheet['A1'] = value in row 15 and columns 3 in file 1 ? There is no sheet when we import into dataframe so..

Comment: row = 15
column = 1
print(sheet.cell(row, column).value)

Comment: I found it, it's with iloc

Comment: for dataframes u can try df.iloc[15, 1]

Comment: Do you know how to put the sheet['A7'] = '= SUM(A1:A2)' into another sheet ? I just want the sum

Comment: just create another sheet & place the req data sheet2=wb.create_sheet('Sheet 2'),sheet2['A1']= sheet['A7'] .value

Comment: The .value take the formula, how to have only the value ?

Comment: try dataonly attribute ,wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True) - if the answer helps kindly accept

Comment: I don't understand, I don't need to load an excel without formula. I just want to pass value to another sheet.